# Unable to launch Nativescript App in iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

when I run tns run ios, i get the following error:

```
Unable to apply changes on device: E152B60E-D109-4BF3-A03A-F1DC42AB9252. Error is: Command xcrun with arguments simctl install E152B60E-D109-4BF3-A03A-F1DC42AB9252 /Applications/nativeOne/HelloApp/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloApp.app failed with exit code 1. Error output:
 An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Could not install at this time.
Failed to chmod /Users/dim/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E152B60E-D109-4BF3-A03A-F1DC42AB9252/data/Bundle/Application/51605A25-4EC5-4D66-9E5D-4EFE1F9632AF/HelloApp.app/HelloApp : No such file or directory
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
    Failed to chmod /Users/dim/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E152B60E-D109-4BF3-A03A-F1DC42AB9252/data/Bundle/Application/51605A25-4EC5-4D66-9E5D-4EFE1F9632AF/HelloApp.app/HelloApp : No such file or directory
```

I've tried everthing possible, re-installed node.
flushed my cache...

the simulator works fine with flutter apps.

Nativescript CLI works fine with Android emulator. The only prob;em is getting it gto work on ios one.
Please help

Comment: I have the same issue, but it builds on physical device @MarsRover did you mange to resolve this issue?